# Too Many Re Renders React JS - useState

Tags: reactjs, loops, babeljs

I have a mapped list of items as radio buttons. I am toggling the checked state.

I get an error from `setCheckedState({i: false});` causing too many re renders.

How would I go about fixing this?

```
// Import useState
import { useState } from 'react';

// Set your active and SetActive items
const [active, setActive] = useState({});

{Object.values(equipment).map((item, i) => {
    // Defautl the item to non active
    setActive({i:false});
    return (
        <IonItem key={item}>
            <IonLabel>{item}</IonLabel>
            <IonRadio mode="md" slot="start" value={item} checked={active.i} onClick={() => {
                // Set the specific Item to active
                setActive({i:!active.i});
            }} />
        </IonItem>
    );
})}
```

Comment: You can't set the state while you're rendering, cos setting state causes a re-render, and thus will lead to an infinite loop. Set the default values of your state when declaring it with `useState`

Comment: That makes sense and I tried that, but It ends up toggling all of the radio buttons instead of just the one clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jayce444 indicated, `setActive({i:false});` in the render will get you into trouble because of the infinite loop.

As an aside, you're calling `setActive` incorrectly.
Calling `setActive({i:!active.i})` will completely overwrite the state object to be a single key/value pair. An example:

let's say you start with

```js
active = {1: true, 2: false}
 // then you call
setActive({2:!active.2}) // now active looks like {2:!false} = {2: true}
// then you call
setActive({1:!active.1}) // now active looks like {1:!undefined} = {1: true}
// in this case you just happen to be getting lucky because
// all <IonRadio ... checked={active.i} ../> (other than your current set i)
// are evaluating to checked={undefined} which is the same as unchecked
```

The thing you're missing is to copy the existing state before updating the particular key. So putting it all together here is a possible solution ([CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-einstein-69c1f?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark))

```js
  const [active, setActive] = useState({});

  const [oneOnly, setOneOnly] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>If you want to have multiple selections</h3>
      {Object.values(equipment).map((item, i) => (
        <label>
          <input
            key={item+"multi"}
            type="radio"
            value={item+"multi"}
            checked={active[item] || false}
            onClick={e => {
              setActive({ ...active, [item]: !active[item] });
            }}
          />
          {i}) {item}
          <br />
        </label>
      ))}
      <h3>... Or just one</h3>
      {Object.values(equipment).map((item, i) => (
        <label>
          <input
            key={item + "single"}
            type="radio"
            value={item + "single"}
            checked={oneOnly === item}
            onClick={e => {
              setOneOnly(item);
            }}
          />
          {i}) {item}
          <br />
        </label>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
// Import useState
import { useState } from 'react';

// Set your active and SetActive items
const [active, setActive] = useState({});

{Object.values(equipment).map((item, i) => {
    // Defautl the item to non active
    setActive(prev => {...prev, [i]: false});
    return (
        <IonItem key={item}>
            <IonLabel>{item}</IonLabel>
            <IonRadio mode="md" slot="start" value={item} checked={active[i]} onClick={() => {
                // Set the specific Item to active
                setActive(prev => {...prev, [i]:!prev[i]});
            }} />
        </IonItem>
    );
})}
```